# How to select spcific elements next to each other in css

Tags: html, css

My HTML structure is like this:

```
input span input
```

Now, I want to select the first and the second input by searching for elements that have a structure like that. I've tried with the + operator but with that, I can only select the second input like this:

```
input + span + input
```

I need to select the first input at the same time as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting adjacent and previous siblings in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636549/selecting-adjacent-and-previous-siblings-in-css)

Comment: It's the same question but the answer only says that it can't be done, so it's not helpful

Comment: It is helpful - you cannot do that with CSS - **that is the answer**. If you want another solution that is not CSS based, update your question to include JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing your actual structure looks something like this

```
<input />
<span></span>
<input />
```

and you want to be able to access the input elements? And this structure can be repeated throughout the html?

If thats the case you will need to use something like ajax/jquery to do this. In javascript you can do something like this ...

```
<input id="input1" class="" />
<span></span>
<input id="input2" class="" />
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('input1').className = "class1";
document.getElementById('input2').className = "class2";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I properly understand, but if your code is something like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email />
<span> Take your time and enter your age </span>
<input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age />
```

Your CSS selector should only be input, as this piece of code:

```css
input {
    background-color: #fabada;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<span> Take your time and enter your age </span>
<input type="number" name="age" placeholder="Age />
```

This should cover both elements (and any other input element you have in your document). If you want to know more, this is an amazing online game to understand CSS selectors https://flukeout.github.io/ Enjoy